# String Split ASP.NET /C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am processing CSV File

Say

```
ABC|06|001
PPP|06|001
```

I am running LINQ to split the CSV

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/CSV.txt");
var _collectCSGData = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
                      let parts = line.Split('|')
                       select new { ID = parts[0],Assignment=parts[1]};
```

How to  get the last item of each line ?

(i.e)

```
001
001
```

Comment: This looks more like pipe-delimited text, not CSV.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary - If it is delimited by columns then it seems people just call it CSV, regardless ofthe delimiter, as it is something that can be imported into Excel easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
select line.Split('|').LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: +1 - OK, this looks like a great answer. I have never used this function.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
parts[parts.length -1]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - True, but you can just put in a check: parts.length > 0 ? parts[parts.length - 1] : ""

Answer (score 1):

```
var _collectCSGData = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path) 
                      let parts = line.Split('|') 
                      let assignment = parts[parts.length - 1]
                       select assignment;
```

This should work, if you need to massage data, `let` is your friend.

**UPDATE:**

Since parts may be empty you can have:

```
let assignment = parts.length > 0 ? parts[parts.length - 1] : String.Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's the third part, how about adding to your anonymous constructor:

```
var _collectCSGData = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
                      let parts = line.Split('|');
                      select new 
                         {ID = parts[0], Assignment = parts[1], Data = parts[2]};
```

Or, if it's just "The last Item no matter how many items"

```
var _collectCSGData = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
                      let parts = line.Split('|');
                      select new 
                        {ID = parts[0], Assignment = parts[1], Data = parts[part.length-1]};
```